# Angular/RxJS - There is a RxJS pipe for stream started?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, stream, reactive-programming

Im trying to create a way to present and hide loading screen dinamically when resolving some stream.

Here is my current code:

```
this.requestService
        .get<Checkout>(`check/${orderNumber}`)
        .pipe(
            tap(() => this.startLoading()),  //i think this isnt the right way to use this pipe
            finalize(() => this.endLoading())
        )
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                data.orderNumber = orderNumber
                this.checkout.next(data)
            },
            error => {
                this.notification.warning(error)
            }
        )
```

The expected result is when my stream start, present loading screen with `startLoading()` end when operation is done, hide loading using `endLoading()`.

My working code:

```
this.startLoading() //basically calling function before i create the stream

this.requestService
        .get<Checkout>(`check/${orderNumber}`)
        .pipe(                
            finalize(() => this.endLoading())
        )
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                data.orderNumber = orderNumber
                this.checkout.next(data)
            },
            error => {
                this.notification.warning(error)
            }
        )
```

Im using this `tap` pipe correctly? Is there another pipe to better resolve this?

What is the best way to do this using RxJS?

Comment: Using the first example my ```startLoading()``` function isnt called when stream start

Comment: are you looking to do this in globally or in one component?

Comment: In a angular service, but i dont see if it matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, your tap runs after your http request has completed.

Ultimately, you would just call `this.startLoading()` before you start the http request.

```js
this.startLoading();
this.requestService.get<Checkout>(`check/${orderNumber}`).pipe(
  finalize(() => this.endLoading())
).subscribe(() => {

});
```

If you **really** want to call `this.startLoading()` in a pipe you could call it before the http request starts by starting off with your own observable:

```js
return of(null).pipe(
  tap(() => this.startLoading()),
  concatMap(() => this.requestService.get<Checkout>(`check/${orderNumber}`)),
  finalize(() => this.endLoading())
).subscribe(() => {

});
```

But then there's not really much point in doing that.

So your `tap` syntax is correct, it's just not executing when you think it should be.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform side-effects on every observable subscription you can warp the source with `defer()`.

```
import { defer } from 'rxjs';

...

defer(() => {
  this.startLoading();
  return this.requestService.get<Checkout>(`check/${orderNumber}`);
}).pipe(
    finalize(() => this.endLoading())
  )
  .subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `BehaviorSubject` and RxJs `defer` with the `finalize` pipe to keep track of the loading process.

```
import { defer } from 'rxjs';

// ...

public this.loading: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

// ...

public getOrder(orderNumber): Observable<Checkout> {
  defer(() => {
    this.loading.next(true);
    return this.requestService.get<Checkout>(`check/${orderNumber}`);
  }).pipe(
    finalize(() => this.loading.next(false)
  );
}

// to get boolean from BehaviorSubject -> is loading
public isLoading(): boolean {
  return this.loading.value;
}

// ...
```

You can now also use `this.loading` observable outside of your class, for example to show or hide a loader based on the observable value:

```
// logs to console each time loading state changes
serviceName.loading.subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe later, since loader is a behavior subject it is multicast and will lead to memory leaks if not unsubscribing.